# Can i configure Firefox to recognize a wildcard certificate for all subdomains without prompting for an exception every time?

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

We have an intranet application that generates dynamic subdomains.  We access it on, for example:

```
dev.myapp.com
```

and the dynamic subdomains that are generated look like:

```
1234.dev.myapp.com
5678.dev.myapp.com
```

We'd like it to be accessed with https, and we've created a self-signed wildcard certificate for it that covers:

```
*.dev.myapp.com
```

The problem is that, every time we hit a new subdomain, we get the warning page and have to add another exception for that one.  Is there any way to configure Firefox so that it will accept this wildcard certificate for ALL subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create your own CA and issue the certs from there. After adding the CA main cert to Firefox, it will accept all certs without asking.